# Can a git refspec include multiple wildcards?

Tags: git, git-refspec

Running `git ls-remote origin` on a repo I have access to, I see branches of the following form, using [git namespaces](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces).

```
refs/namespaces/share/refs/namespaces/<username>/refs/heads/<branch-name>
```

I'd like to map these to `refs/remotes/<username>/<branch-name>`.

This [github help page](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247) gives an example of how to solve a simpler version of this problem, by adding this to the `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

I can make things work for my case with:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/namespaces/share/refs/namespaces/USER1/refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/USER1/*
    fetch = +refs/namespaces/share/refs/namespaces/USER2/refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/USER2/*
    # etc
```

But this requires me to know all the usernames ahead of time. Unfortunately, using two `*`s doesn't work:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/namespaces/share/refs/namespaces/*/refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/*/*
```

Is there way of achieving this remapping?

Answer (score 1):

No—or more precisely, not short of writing a program to write a series of `fetch =` lines.

You could write such a program using a sort of meta-configuration (stored in `.git/config` or somewhere else, it does not really matter at this level).  The program would run `git ls-remote` on the remote, compute the appropriate `fetch =` lines, and update `.git/config` to contain them.

If you name this program, say, `git-synchrofetch` (this name is meant to harken back to [synchromesh](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synchromesh)), you could have it invoke `git fetch` after updating `.git/config`.  Then instead of `git fetch origin` you might run `git synchrofetch origin`, to update your default fetches and then fetch.

(Note that the program could also just invoke `git fetch` directly with a full set of refspecs, but the idea here would be to let most of the other Git code operate as normal and only do a resynchronization when you think the set of user names has changed.)

Comment: The git developers talked about adding this functionality a while back, see: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/RFC-Refspec-patterns-with-in-the-middle-td2406738.html, but that conversation ended with the primary git developer's comment "Isn't this just getting more and more insane?  Is this really worth 
supporting, I have to wonder... "